# while loop chars C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, char

I'm working on a Programming assignment and I can't figure out why this while loop is looping infinitely. There has been other input before this loop occurs, but I have cin.ignore() to clear any junk out before this loop. I'm scratching my brain, help?

```
//Prompt for readiness
    char ready = 'x';
    while (ready != 'Y' || ready != 'y') {
        cout << "READY TO START YOUR TURN " << playerName << "? ";
        ready = cin.get();
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to change `||` (OR) to `&&` (AND). Also, reset the stream after you read with `cin.get()`, i.e. put the following line after:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
std::cin.clear();
```

(you need to `#include <limits>`)

Otherwise, `cin.get()` returns a `char` and leaves an extra `\n` (newline) in the stream, that gets read once more and you basically end up with the loop executing twice for each non-yes response.

Comment: Aaaaand, I feel like a dummy now. Literally the one thing I haven't checked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

think of boolean algebra. OR gate results in true if one or both sides are true. so, if you input `'y'` or `'Y'`, your statement will result in returning true, since of the sides would still be true. 

if you change `||` to `&&` (AND gate), which returns true only if both of the sides are true, then your statement makes sense. user inputs `'y'` or `'Y'` (he's ready, so get him out of that loop!) and one of the sides is equal to false, hence loop terminates.

```
while (ready != 'Y' && ready != 'y') {
```

or

```
while (ready == 'Y' || ready == 'y') {
```

are statements that you meant.

Comment: thanks for this insight! been having this problem for quite a time now. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

change the code to this -

```
    char ready = 'x';
    while (ready != 'Y' && ready != 'y') {
        cout << "READY TO START YOUR TURN " << playerName << "? ";
        ready = cin.get();
    }
```

It will resolve your issue.